# appscript functions work well seperately but not when combined together, trying to copy a sheet from a spreadsheet into a new folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

very new to javascript and appscript, this is what I have so far given my limited exposure to the language, so please correct any misconceptions I have through my code:

GOAL: to copy a single sheet from a spreadsheet into a new google drive folder.

METHOD: i spend last couple of days finding a way to do it but I couldn't so I decided to brute force it step by step using the logic I understand; first function i will cop the entire spreadsheet into a new folder, then my second function i will loop through the sheets in the new copied spreadsheet and delete all sheets except the one I want. I know it's not efficient but it's the best idea i could come up with.

ISSUE: both functions worked perfectly well separately, but when I combine them together on the same script, the delete function does not work. Here is what I have so far separately and together:

the first function to make copy of the spreadsheet using its ID which works fine is

```
function exportedSheet() {
  let targetSheet = DriveApp.getFileById("INSERT ORIGINAL SHEET ID");
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("INSERT DESTINATION FOLDER ID");
  var finalFile=DriveApp.getFileById(targetSheet.getId()).makeCopy("NEW FILE NAME", destFolder);
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(finalFile.getId());
}
```

the second function to delete all the sheets in the new file except the desired sheet, let's call it "KEEP" is this, which also works fine:

```
function DeleteAllSheets() {
  let ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(NEW OBTAINED SHEET ID FROM THE LAST FUNCTION ADDED MANUALLY);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
    case "KEEP":
    break;
    default:
    ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

now here is what i did to combine them into one script that would ultimately create the new copy spreadsheet, then pull the ID of the new spreadsheet the first function created from the function itself? and apply it to the second function so it can be accessed and deleted unwatned sheets. I assume this logic makes sense, but it's clealry not since the code isn't running correctly.

I decided to finished the first function that creates the copy by returning a variable with the file i created, then i tried to call that function exportedSheet() in the second function so that I can call the .getID() method from it, my logic is that the second function will pull the variable from the first function and then apply it to the rest of the code

```
function exportedSheet() {
  let targetSheet = DriveApp.getFileById("INSERT ORIGINAL SHEET ID");
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("INSERT DESTINATION FOLDER ID");
  var finalFile=DriveApp.getFileById(targetSheet.getId()).makeCopy("test", destFolder);
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(finalFile.getId());
  return finalFile
} 

function DeleteAllSheets() {
  var test= exportedSheet();
  let ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(test.getId());;
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    switch(sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
    case "KEEP":
    break;
    default:
    ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

if you run the code however, the new copied spreadsheet will appear, but it will include all the sheets within it rather than deleting them except the one I need. this is the extent of what i did in the past 5 hours and i can't remember all the other things i tried to tinker with it so it works. If you read this far thank you, I appreciate any input!

Comment: Hi, I have tried to replicate what you have. I have tested the combined function and it's working perfectly. It creates a new spreadsheet and only keeps the "KEEP" sheet. If you want we can discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248977/room-for-shadow-reaper-and-oak)

Answer (score 1):

Copy sheets to new spreadsheet in another folder

```
function copysheetstonewspreadsheet() {
  const fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getName().startsWith("Sheet"));//did not want to mess around with other sheets
  shts.forEach(sh => {
    let f = SpreadsheetApp.create(sh.getName());
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": fldr.getId()}]}, f.getId());
    let d = SpreadsheetApp.openById(f.getId());
    sh.copyTo(d);
    d.deleteSheet(d.getSheets()[0]);//There is only one sheet in a new spreadsheet
  });
}
```

- [Drive.Files.Update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)

Comment: WOW thank you this seems way more efficient than mine, I will give it a try.

Comment: Also wanted to note literally after posting this and playing more with it I realized making the whole code block into one function instead of breaking it into two solves my whole issue, and im not sure how i've completely overlooked that. i apologize if this seemed elementary i'm still learning this. thank you again